# Using UNION with ORDER BY does not produce expected results in Sybase

Tags: sorting, union, sybase

I have a list of Currencies E.g, USD, AED, INR, EUR, GBP (in order of entry in table Currencies). I need to prepare a query with all currencies including 'ALL' as well but sorted with 'ALL' appearing as the first one.

Expected result should be in the following order:

```
ALL
AED
EUR
GBP
INR
USD
```

My SQL is:

```
SELECT 'ALL' Currency
UNION ALL
SELECT Currency FROM Currencies ORDER BY Currency
```

However, the above SQL produces with AED as the first one due to sorting.

```
AED
ALL
EUR
GBP
INR
USD
```

Help appreciated to get 'ALL' on top.

Comment: You may have to add a numeric rank value to force a particular order.

Comment: Surprising: If talking about Sybase ASE, I thought UNION ALL, unlike simply UNION, should just concatenate both results. And also, that ORDER BY should operate only over the second select, not over the combined result set. What if you surround the second select in parenthesis to make it clear to whom belongs the ORDER BY clause? SELECT 'ALL' Currency
UNION ALL
(SELECT Currency FROM Currencies ORDER BY Currency)

Comment: Adding a numeric prefix for currencies does not add value to my users.

Comment: Tried parenthesis in all combinations and none of them worked.

Comment: Tried this:
SELECT 'ALL'
UNION ALL
(SELECT Currency FROM kplus..Currencies) 
ORDER BY Currency
----
As well as this:
SELECT 'ALL'
UNION ALL
(SELECT Currency FROM kplus..Currencies
ORDER BY Currency)

Comment: Looks like a Sybase issue :(. Using Sybase 
Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 18763 ESD#4

Comment: The *only* part of SQL that dictates the order of results is an `ORDER BY` clause. Other parts of the language (such as `UNION ALL`) say *nothing* about the order in which results are returned. So, if you want results in a particular order, you'd better make sure that your `ORDER BY` clause specifies your requirements precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "Rank" column which is used in the ordering, and use a derived table that you order and select the Currency column from:

```
SELECT Currency FROM (
    SELECT 'ALL' Currency, 1 Rank
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Currency, 2 Rank FROM Currencies
) t
ORDER BY Rank, Currency
```